# Recently I configured a Site-2-Site VPN Tunnel and I'm getting this errors:

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, cisco-vpn

Recently I configured a Site-2-Site VPN Tunnel and I'm getting this errors:

```
3   Feb 27 2018 09:21:57    Tunnel Manager has failed to establish an L2L SA.  All configured IKE versions failed to establish the tunnel. Map Tag= TTL_map.  Map Sequence Number = 1.
3   Feb 27 2018 09:21:57    Group = 10.249.7.13, IP = 10.249.7.13, Removing peer from correlator table failed, no match!
3   Feb 27 2018 09:21:57    Group = 10.249.7.13, IP = 10.249.7.13, QM FSM error (P2 struct &0x00007fff383352e0, mess id 0xb3f7fd67)!
```

I did research and applied many solutions they recommended, but there is no result.

> How can I solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The above error message indicates that negotiation of IKE (Internet Key Exchange) has failed because there is no match between ISAKMP (Internet Security Association Key Management Protocol) policies between the two endpoints. Basically its either mis-configured or just not configured correctly. You can determine the details of any active ISAKMP policies with :

```
Router#show crypto isakmp policy
```

The details on both sides of the VPN should be compatible ie have same encryption algorithm, hash algorithm, authentication method.